# Zend Framework 2 - Adapters

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm new in Zend Framework and I'va got a question.

I have 20 modules in my CMS, all of modules using APC Cache Adapter (defined in module configuration), And now I want to change this adapter to Memcache.

Is there any good practice instead of changing all of config.module.php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you setup your Cache/Cache adapter using DI/Service Manager then you should be able to change this very simply by changing the definition inside the Service Manager Config.

Service Manager Config:

```
    'My\Cache' => function($sm){
        $cache = \Zend\Cache\StorageFactory::factory(array(
            'adapter' => 'filesystem',
            'plugins' => array(
                'exception_handler' => array('throw_exceptions' => FALSE),
                'serializer'
            )
        ));

        $cache->setOptions(array(
            'cache_dir' => './data/cache',
            'ttl'       => 60*60,
        ));

        return $cache;
    },
```

You could then just change the adapter and setup inside the SM. All modules would use the Service manager to consume the cache so they would not need anything further changed.

Some Module:

```
<?php $cache = $this->getServiceManager()->get('My\Cache'); ?>
```